# Virtual Function access through multiple interfaces

Tags: c++

I just stumbled across an compile error and I am wondering why this occurs.
The code:

```
struct Foo1
{
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};
struct Foo2 : Foo1
{
    virtual int foo(int i) = 0;
};
struct Bar : public Foo2
{
    virtual int foo() { return 0; }
    virtual int foo(int i) { return i; }
};
int main() {
    Bar b;
    Foo2* f2 = &b;
    b.foo();
    //f2->foo(); // this gives an error
    return 0;
}
```

The error on a gcc 4.8.1 is

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo2::foo()’

I am wondering why the compiler cannot see the `Foo1::foo` function?
I know that I can fix this by adding `using Foo1::foo` to the `Foo2` class, but can anyone give me a reference to the standard why the compiler is not able to find the function by itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From *N3797*

**3.3.10/3 Name hiding**

> In a member function definition, the declaration of a name at block scope hides the declaration of a member of the class with the same name; see 3.3.7. **The declaration of a member in a derived class (Clause 10) hides the declaration of a member of a base class of the same name**. see 10.2.

So `Foo2::foo()` hides `Foo1::foo()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The phenomenon is also called "name hiding" IIRC and basically states that declarations in a base class are hidden if there's a declaration with the same name in the derived class. It is by design to avoid some "contrived" behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

The `foo` in the derived class hides the `foo` with different signature of the base class.

To say that you want the overloads of the base included you need to add a `using` declaration to `Foo2`:

```
struct Foo2 : Foo1
{
    using Foo1::foo;
    virtual int foo(int i) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Correct, although he was also asking for a reference to that.

Comment: @MarcoA.: Yeah, see Rakibul's answer for that.